# SLURM: How to submit a job to a remote slurm cluster from another server?

Tags: slurm

I have the main server-'**A**' hosting the SLURM cluster. The set up is working fine as expected.

I wanted to know if there is a way to submit the jobs to that main server from another server- '**B**' remotely and get the responses.

This situation arises because I don't want to give access to the terminal of the main server- '**A**' to the users on '**B**'.

I have gone through the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html) and [FAQs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html), but unfortunately couldn't find the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the Slurm client on Server B . Copy your slurm.conf to it and then ensure it has the correct authentication (i.e the correct Munge key) , it should work.